# WebSocket4Net - 'return' Message Received on websocket

Tags: c#, websocket

I'm using WebSocket4Net to communicate my xamarin android app with a server. I can send and receive messages from my app, but I don't know how to get the incoming message (which is received in webSocket_MessageReceived) in my Send method. I was googling how to do it with a callback but couldn't implement it.
Any help is appreciated.

This is in my WebSocketHelper class:

```
        private WebSocket webSocket;
        private string outgoingMessage;

        public WebSocketHelper(string url)
        {
            webSocket = new WebSocket(url);
            webSocket.Opened += new EventHandler((sender, e) => webSocket_Opened(sender, e, this.outgoingMessage));
            webSocket.Error += new EventHandler<SuperSocket.ClientEngine.ErrorEventArgs>(webSocket_Error);
            //webSocket.Closed += new EventHandler(webSocket_Closed);
            webSocket.MessageReceived += new EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs>(webSocket_MessageReceived);
        }

        public string Send(string message)
        {
            this.outgoingMessage = message;

            webSocket.Open();

            //Get message received from websocket to return it

            return ""; //TEMP return
        }

        private void webSocket_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e, string message)
        {
            webSocket.Send(message);
        }

        private void webSocket_Error(object sender, SuperSocket.ClientEngine.ErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            string errorMessage = e.Exception.Message;

            //return errorMessage to Send method (not sure), this is secondary
        }

        private void webSocket_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string incomingMessage = e.Message;

            //I need to return incomingMessage to Send method
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do two things:

1. To introduce a `WebSocketHelper` member of type `string` through
   which you'll pass string value from event handler
   `webSocket_MessageReceived` to another method (`Send`)
2. To make `Send` waiting till `webSocket_MessageReceived` handler is
   called. You can use [AutoResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this (it should be available in Xamarin library for Android).

Mind that `_messageReceivedEvent.WaitOne` makes your `Send` method blocking so if you are calling this method from UI event handler, your UI will be unresponsive till `_messageReceivedEvent.Set` is called. Think about redesigning this class so it uses async approach (it could expose event `MessageReceivedEvent` to which UI is subscribed...).

```
    public class WebSocketHelper : IDisposable
    {
       private string _incomingMessage;
       private AutoResetEvent _messageReceivedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
       ...

       public string Send(string message)
       {
          this.outgoingMessage = message;
          webSocket.Open();
          this._messageReceivedEvent.WaitOne(); 
          return this._incomingMessage; 
       }

       private void webSocket_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
       {
          this._incomingMessage = e.Message;
          this._messageReceivedEvent.Set();
       }

       ...
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I'd like to redesign this so the UI stays responsive, by now this works, thanks!!